# Top Bar Chat login bug

Tags: bug

I am logged into SharePoint.StackExchange and whenever I use the top bar to get into the SharePoint chat, it doesn't automatically log me in, stating that I need to log in to an existing StackExchange site in order to get logged in automatically.

[image]

Comment: I had this problem to! When I started logging in with Google account instead of Facebook, it started working better.. What kind of login do you use?

Comment: What happens when you try it via the [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m9AAm.png)?

Comment: that works, but it's a little confusing, thinking that it will auto-login you in, which it normally does.